# I use httpclient crawl pages,but why it was blocked

Tags: java, httpclient

```
method = new GetMethod(strUrl);
log.info("Befor execueteMechod");
statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
log.info("After execueteMechod");
```

---

I write this java codes to crawl web pages,  it runs in a server. after a few days , today I was disappointed to found the crawl thread was blocked. From the log i could say it was blocked in **executeMethod** method. Could someone tell me how to deal with this problem.

And also, it reported twice 504 or 503 warnings, when the third time crawing this page, the problem occured, the thread blocked, i don't want this.

Comment: is this piece of code running in threads? it looks as if you are trying to send too many requests in quick succession to the strUrl.